# Sum of the elements of a list of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a list of arrays that looks like this (the dimensions of each array and the length of the list are not necessarily fixed):

```
mylist = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]]),
         np.array([[1,2],[1,2]]),
         np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6,7]]),
         np.array([1,2])
```

I would like to get the sum of all the elements of the list, and get a single float at the end.

For this case the result would be:

```
sum = 1+2 + 3+4 + 5+6 + 7+8 +9+10 +
      1+2 + 1+2 + 
      1+2+3+4+5 + 3+4+5+6+7 +
      1+2
```

Comment: `sum([np.sum(i) for i in l])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note your input isn't syntactically correct Python. Once you have correctly defined a `list` of `np.ndarray` objects, you can use `sum` with a generator expression:

```
L = [np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]]),
     np.array([[1,2],[1,2]]),
     np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6,7]]),
     np.array([1,2])]

res = sum(i.sum() for i in L)  # 104
```

In addition, *never* shadow built-ins, so don't name your variables `list` or `sum`.

---

If one of your 2 dimensions are the same size across all your arrays, you can combine them into a single array and then use a vectorised method:

```
L = [np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]]),
     np.array([[1,2],[1,2]]),
     np.array([[1,3],[2,4],[3,5],[4,6],[5,7]]),
     np.array([1,2])]

res = np.vstack(L).sum()  # 104
```

Comment: Any alternative solution without using 'for'? Performance is also important in this case

Comment: @Sebas_n1, This is non-vectorisable. You can tell this because there's no one dimension which has the same size across all your arrays.